# How to form array in do while loop with input validation?

Tags: java

```
public class Array {

  public static void main ( String[] args ) {


    int DAYS_SIZE = 5;
    double[] sales = new double[DAYS_SIZE];

    String input;
    char userResponse;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int index = 0;

    do {
        index++;
        System.out.print("Enter sales for day " + index  + ": ");
        sales[index] = keyboard.nextInt();             

        System.out.print("Another ( y or n )? " );
        input = keyboard.next();
        userResponse = input.charAt(0);

     } while ( userResponse == 'Y' || userResponse == 'y');   

  }
}
```

I keep getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: 5 at the last day

I know why this is happening but i dont know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

you increase your index before you access the array without checking whether the index is already bigger than the size of the array. When the user enters days and days index will become bigger than 5 in your case.

Also as the index starts with 0 and not with 1, there is no index 5, but only 0-4

Comment: Should i add a decision structure that checks whether if the index is bigger than the size of the array, or is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you need to increment `index` straight away? Just move it to the bottom of your iteration.

Comment: i put it at the bottom and i still get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: when i input the sales for the last day which would be 5.

Comment: because you never check whether the index is bigger than the size of the array. You can either add the `index < sales.length` check in your while condition or separately if you like to give the user an extra message like "no more days left" or so